# binomial coefficient

Tags: c++, binomial-coefficients

I have a code which calculate binomial coefficient, but when number is bigger then 20, it start to calculate wrong, where is the problem? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long int bin(long int x)
{
    if(x==0)
        return 1;
    long int r = x;
    for(int i = r-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        r = r*i;
    }
    return r;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Write n and k: " << endl;
    long int n=0;
    long int k=0;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    long int result = 0;
    long int fn = bin(n);
    long int fk = bin(k);
    long int fnk = bin(n-k);


    result = fn/(fk*fnk);

    cout << endl << "C = " << result << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

for example 12 and 5 = 792 which is correct, but 20 and 4 = -2 which is not correct

Comment: You are exceeding the range of `long int` with those factorials; you may get a bit further with the ["alternate definition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) of the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your `bin` function computes the factorial. The factorial of 21 doesn't fit in a `long`.

You're already relying on an implementation detail. `long` is only required to be 32 bits, but on your system it's 64. If it were only 32, then you'd fail much sooner.

Comment: Ah.. thans, so actually the program is correct but the data types are not large enought.

Comment: Yes, you could use a larger type (which requires a library like GMP) or you could re-write the code to do the multiplications and divisions in a different order so that the intermediate values in your calculation are smaller.

Comment: @SteveJessop: true, but won't solve the issue completely, because the central binomial coefficient still grows (almost) exponentially.

Comment: @ybungalobill: agreed, changing the order of calculations allows computing some coefficients that the current code can't, but of course still doesn't allow computing arbitrarily large results. The central coefficient grows *actually* exponentially, since the sum of coefficients is `2^n`, there are `n+1` of them, and the largest value in any set is greater than or equal to the mean.

Answer (score 2):

20! = 2432902008176640000, which is far beyond what `long int` can hold (typically 2147483647). Use `double` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating the factorial of n using

```
bin(n);
```

You are running past the limit of long when n is >=20.

As @SteveJessop pointed out in the comments, You would overrun the limit even if you used **unsigned long long** (the longest fixed-point type) which has a range
from `0 to 18446744073709551615`

You could use an int-array to store your result as detailed **[here](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/factorial-of-big-numbers-in-c.html)**.

Comment: `unsigned long long` would fail at the same point, the questioner already has a 64 bit `long`.