# Codechef/SPOJ : 'Marbles' Runtime Error

Tags: c

I've tried the Marbles pkroblem on spoj - (link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/MARBLES/ )

However I'm getting Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) after multiple tries.

Here's the code I submitted -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int comb(long int n, long int k)
{

if (n==k || k==0)
    return 1;
else
    return (comb(n-1, k) + comb(n-1, k-1));
}

int main() {

int t;
long int n, k;
scanf("%d", &t);
while(t--)

{
    scanf("%ld %ld", &n, &k);
    printf("%d\n", comb(n-1, k-1));

}

return 0;
}
```

I cant understand why I'm getting the error. Other solutions on the internet have all used iterative way to calculate the nCr combination. I've tried using a recursive approach. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are decrementing `n` in the recursion but you don't check the case when `n` becomes 0 or negative, so the segfaul basically tells you that you get into an infinite recursion.

just add some stop criterion in addition to `n==k || k==0`.

I didn't look at the problem description so I don't know what the correct condition is, but perhaps you need something like

```
if (n==k || k==0 || n==0)
```

Comment: I did what you said, and it does seem right. But I'm still getting the same runtime error. 
The problem is basically to calculate nCr (PnC) where n and r are very large. Therefore, instead of explicitly calculating factorials, I have used the identity nCr = (n-1)Cr + (n-1)C(r-1) in the recursive function.

Comment: well in most default settings, there's only a limited number of recursive function calls since they all need space on the stack. on linux, `ulimit -s` can sometimes be used to increase the size of the stack, but it is still not a solution for *very* large numbers.

Comment: just look for a non-recursive solution, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156584/binomial-coefficient, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671614/binomial-coefficient-in-c etc.